# Android game using surfaceview, canvas - Drawable or bitmap

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am developing a game in `SurfaceView`. It involves around 15 - 20 images of some are large having average resolution of 320X400. I have two questions-

1. I am using images as `Drawable` and using `draw(canvas)` method of drawable to draw images on screen. I see in some games people use `Bitmap` instead of Drawable to draw images on screen, what is the difference between using images as `Drawable` or `Bitmap` in android game. Which is more memory efficient and which has good performance while drawing on canvas?
2. Right now I am creating arrays of `Drawable` and creating Drawable object of all images used in game and putting them into there respective array, as all images are required while gameplay. I want to know which is better - loading all images in Drawable on start or creating Drawable Object when we need it and making null others that are not shown and repeating this process each time images are shown or removed from screen. Will repeating the process of creating and nulling objects have any bad effect or is it better than loading all images at once?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. According to my experience Bitmap is faster than drawable. I'm testing an app that works at 40-45 fps with drawable and with bitmap I get 57-59 fps. That's because people use them for games.
2. If you have enough memory I recommend you to load all the images first. If you start creating and destroying objects it will call the garbage collector often and it's really slow. If you don't need a hight performance, create and destroy objects will reduce the use of memory. If you are trying to make a game maybe this link could help.

[Google I/O 2009 - Writing Real-Time Games for Android](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4Bk5rmIpic) especially min 22:30 Fast java code

Answer (score 2):

Talking from personal experience you should go with [Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) rather than [Drawables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html). This will yield better results.

A Bitmap will suit your options best, since all you needing (as for as I can tell) is a picture to be displayed on the screen.

A Drawable has a wider scope (Documentation from the Android Dev. website):

> A Drawable is a general abstraction for "something that can be drawn."
>   Most often you will deal with Drawable as the type of resource
>   retrieved for drawing things to the screen; the Drawable class
>   provides a generic API for dealing with an underlying visual resource
>   that may take a variety of forms. Unlike a View, a Drawable does not
>   have any facility to receive events or otherwise interact with the
>   user.

Definitely load all your Bitmaps before the Game starts; This is a clean approach. If you don't, your game could lag, due to the GC.

You can create a class that contains all the static Bitmap fields.

```
public static Bitmap foo;
```

Then in your activity class you can load these Bitmaps (I usually put my Bitmaps in the Assets folder):

NB: It's probably best to create a class called LoadScreen or SplashScreen that will take care of all the initializing. If you do it this way, you'll have to pass a reference to your activity class to that class.

```
Assets.foo = readAssetsBitmap("foo.png");

public Bitmap readBitmapFromMemory(String filename) {
        Bitmap defautBitmap = null;
        File filePath = getFileStreamPath(filename);
        FileInputStream fi;
        try {
            fi = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            defautBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi);

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return defautBitmap;

    }
```

When the user decides to exit the game, you should unload all the Bitmaps like so:

```
disposeBitmap(Assets.foo);

public void disposeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        bitmap.recycle();
        bitmap = null;

    }
```

I hope this helps.